# Cherokee gives 500 error

Tags: django, ubuntu, cherokee

django_wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'umka.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

uwsgi.xml

```
<uwsgi>
    <plugins>python</plugins>
    <pythonpath>/var/www/</pythonpath>
    <workers>2</workers>
    <module>umka.django_wsgi</module>
    <app mountpoint="/">
        <script>django_wsgi</script>
    </app>
    <prio>-4</prio>
    <threads>2</threads>
    <harakiri>65</harakiri>
</uwsgi>
```

I can log into cherokee-admin. It says server is running. But it always serves 500 error.

Comment: There's no error messages in the server error logs?

Comment: Nope. everythin's clear in cherokee.error and cherokee.access